# elif statement unreached in Python script

Tags: python, if-statement, input, user-input

In the following code, the `if` statement is reached and runs fine. The `elif` statement however seems to have no effect. When the script is run, when the conditions for the `elif` statement are met, nothing happens and when I press return button twice the script just keeps going skipping the `elif` statement altogether.

My code:

```
            print("If you want to name this window press 1, if you want to describe it press 2")
            if input() == "1":
                print("Please enter this window's title:")
                current_window_title = input()
                print("Do you also want to describe this window? P.S: You can do this later.)")
                if input().lower() == "yes":
                    print("Please enter this window's description:")
                    current_window_description = input()
                else:
                    current_window_description = "None"
            elif input() == "2":
                print("Please enter this window's description:")
                current_window_description = input()
                print("Do you also want to give this window a title? P.S: You can do this later.")
                if input().lower() == "yes":
                    print("Please enter this window's title:")
                    current_window_title = input()
```

Comment: You're asking it to input two separate times.  Each call to `input()` wants you to input a separate number.  You need to write `value = input()`.  Then `if value == "1"`, and `if value == "2"` so its not trying to re-input a second number.

Comment: `elif` means `else if`, so it will only ever be evaluated if the preceding `if` condition is `False` - did you enter something other than a `'1'` first and *then* a `'2'`? However, you probably want to store the input in a variable and use that in your `if .. elif ..`  statement

Comment: @FrankYellin this makes sense and worked, thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because you got an input from the user and in the same range if and this amount of input is not available in elif you can do these two things and it will work properly:

```
print("If you want to name this window press 1, if you want to describe it press 2")
inp = input()
if inp == "1":
    print("Please enter this window's title:")
    current_window_title = input()
    print("Do you also want to describe this window? P.S: You can do this later.)")
    if input().lower() == "yes":
        print("Please enter this window's description:")
        current_window_description = input()
    else:
        current_window_description = "None"
elif inp == "2":
    print("Please enter this window's description:")
    current_window_description = input()
    print("Do you also want to give this window a title? P.S: You can do this later.")
    if input().lower() == "yes":
        print("Please enter this window's title:")
        current_window_title = input()
```

or :

```
print("If you want to name this window press 1, if you want to describe it press 2")
if input() == "1":
    print("Please enter this window's title:")
    current_window_title = input()
    print("Do you also want to describe this window? P.S: You can do this later.)")
    if input().lower() == "yes":
        print("Please enter this window's description:")
        current_window_description = input()
    else:
        current_window_description = "None"
if input() == "2":
    print("Please enter this window's description:")
    current_window_description = input()
    print("Do you also want to give this window a title? P.S: You can do this later.")
    if input().lower() == "yes":
        print("Please enter this window's title:")
        current_window_title = input()
```

Comment: This code still has the problem of redundant input statements, which will result in abrupt behaviour

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

There are too many undesired `input()` statements in the code, which are making it work abruptly.

> Also, as python's input() function also has the capability of printing, you can combine `print()` and `input()` into one statement.

###### All modifications as follows:

```
Input = input("If you want to name this window press 1, if you want to describe it press 2")

if Input == "1":
    current_window_title = input("Please enter this window's title:")

    if input("Do you also want to describe this window? P.S: You can do this later.)").lower() == "yes":
        current_window_description = input("Please enter this window's description:")
    else:
        current_window_description = "None"
        

elif Input == "2":
    current_window_description = input("Please enter this window's description:")
    if input("Do you also want to give this window a title? P.S: You can do this later.").lower() == "yes":
        current_window_title = input("Please enter this window's title:")
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use input variable before if
elif else blocks.

```
answer=input("If you want to name this window press 1, if you want to describe it press 2:")
            if answer == "1":
               Code section 1
           elif answer=="2":
               Code section 2
           else : 
              print ("wrong command")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code would ask for input twice if you wan to reach 2. The first time, it would ask for input, it is in the if statement, you would enter 2 and it wouldn't match. The second time it would ask for an input, you are in the elif statement and it would work.

It is better to get the result of the input then evaluate it.

```
print("If you want to name this window press 1, if you want to describe it press 2")
result = input()
if result == "1":
    print("Please enter this window's title:")
    current_window_title = input()
    print("Do you also want to describe this window? P.S: You can do this later.)")
    if input().lower() == "yes":
        print("Please enter this window's description:")
        current_window_description = input()
    else:
        current_window_description = "None"
elif result == "2":
    print("Please enter this window's description:")
    current_window_description = input()
    print("Do you also want to give this window a title? P.S: You can do this later.")
    if input().lower() == "yes":
        print("Please enter this window's title:")
        current_window_title = input()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the initial `input()` of user input outside of the `if` and `elif` statements, so that they are comparing to the same value. Currently the elif will never capture that input of "2", unless you enter a second input ("2" again). Try something like this.

```
print("If you want to name this window press 1, if you want to describe it press 2")
user_input = input()
if user_input == "1":
    print("Please enter this window's title:")
    current_window_title = input()
    print("Do you also want to describe this window? P.S: You can do this later.)")
    if input().lower() == "yes":
        print("Please enter this window's description:")
        current_window_description = input()
    else:
        current_window_description = "None"
elif user_input == "2":
    print("Please enter this window's description:")
    current_window_description = input()
    print("Do you also want to give this window a title? P.S: You can do this later.")
    if input().lower() == "yes":
        print("Please enter this window's title:")
        current_window_title = input()
```